# What is the VB.NET equivalent of the C# "is" keyword?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I need to check if a given object implements an interface. In C# I would simply say:

```
if (x is IFoo) { }
```

Is using a `TryCast()` and then checking for `Nothing` the best way?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try the following

```
if TypeOf x Is IFoo Then 
  ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
If TypeOf x Is IFoo Then
```

Answer (score 5):

The direct translation is:

```vb
If TypeOf x Is IFoo Then
    ...
End If
```

But (to answer your second question) if the original code was better written as

```cs
var y = x as IFoo;
if (y != null)
{
   ... something referencing y rather than (IFoo)x ...
}
```

Then, yes,

```vb
Dim y = TryCast(x, IFoo)
If y IsNot Nothing Then
   ... something referencing y rather than CType or DirectCast (x, IFoo)
End If
```

is better.