# How to check the type of a DataGridView Cell?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to check the cell type of a DataGridView Cell by using following code:

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "ColCheck" Then
            Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColCheck")
            If cell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then

            End If
```

I am getting `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`  is a type and can not be used as an expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167479/what-is-the-vb-net-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-is-keyword

Comment: Its working.. Thanks. But as you can see I might have never found that question since its title is pretty different. Post this link as answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 2):

i tried this in cell click event and works perfectly :

```
Type str = dgv.Columns[dgv.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex].CellType;
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. You can check then the property str.Name and check if it's a combo, text...

Answer (score 1):

Another method if you know the row and column indexes: dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].GetType().Name