# How to compare inherited type with Base Type?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection, types

I have one method as,

```
public function DoSomethingGenricWithUIControls(ByVal incomingData As Object)
     //Fun Stuff
End Function
```

This method will be get called and can get passed the `Page`,`UserControl`, or any other type.

I want to check the type of incoming object, if it's `Page`,`UserControl` or other type.

But I was unable to do that. Whenever I tried using the `GetType()` of `typeOf()` on `System.Web.UI.UserControl`. It gives,

```
'UserControl' is a type in 'UI' and cannot be used as an expression.
```

When I tried other methods like `.IsAssignableFrom()` and `.IsSubclassOf()` but I was still unable to do that.

One more note my incoming `usercontrols` or `page` can be multiple inherited from different controls/pages. So its immediate base type is not that of `System.Web.UI.<Type>`.

Let me know in case of any confusion. VB/C# any way would work for me.

**UPDATE**

I have tried like,

```
 if( ncomingPage.GetType() Is System.Web.UI.UserControl)
```

This gives me same issue as above,

```
'UserControl' is a type in 'UI' and cannot be used as an expression.
```

Comment: You can check type with [`is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) or simply **try** to cast with [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) and if it's not `null` - then you have needed type instance.

Comment: I dont want to fall into the `try catch` casting, it s not good practice and I have tried with `Is` but still the same issue

Comment: You don't need `try/catch` when using `as/null` [check](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2139818/1997232). Can you post not working code with `is`?

Comment: [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
if( ncomingPage.GetType() is System.Web.UI.UserControl)
```

you have to use

```
// c#
if( ncomingPage is System.Web.UI.UserControl)
// vb.net fist line of code in my life ever! hopefully will compile
If TypeOf ncomingPage Is System.Web.UI.UserControl Then
```

Notice absence of getting object type. `is` does that for you under hoof.

You can check type with simple `as/null` check pattern:

```
var page = ncomgingPage as UserControl;
if(page != null)
{
    ... // ncomingPage is inherited from UserControl
}
```

it is more efficient (only single cast) than using `is` as you will probably do something like

```
// checking type
if( ncomingPage is System.Web.UI.UserControl)
{
    // casting
    ((UserControl)ncomingPage).SomeMethod();
    ...
}
```

Comment: When I do the ` If (incomingPage Is System.Web.UI.UserControl) Then` it still gives the error `'UserControl' is a type in 'UI' and cannot be used as an expression.`

Comment: My answer is in `C#`. It seems in vb.net [`Is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) *is* [different](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3167479/1997232), right side expression should be an object. See edit (vb.net part, where I am trying to use `TypeOf`).